# How to chage the parameters in a LineRectangle class in python kivy?

Tags: python, label, kivy, box

I want to draw multi-box on a image. How to chage the parameters of the box pos, size and lable in a LineRectangle class in python kivy?

```
class LineRectangle(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LineRectangle, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1, 0, 0, 1)
            self.line = Line(width=2, rectangle=(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
            self.label = Label(text='Rectangle', pos=(self.x, self.y), size=(10, 10))


class LineExtendedApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = FloatLayout()
        image = Image(source='000001.jpg', allow_stretch=False, keep_ratio=True)
        root.add_widget(image)
        bbox1 = LineRectangle()
        bbox1.line = Line(width=1, rectangle=(100, 100, 100, 100))
        bbox1.label = Label(text='bbox1', pos=(100, 100), size=(10, 10))
        bbox2 = LineRectangle()
        bbox2.line = Line(width=1, rectangle=(300, 300, 100, 100))
        bbox2.label = Label(text='bbox1', pos=(300, 300), size=(10, 10))
        root.add_widget(bbox1)
        root.add_widget(bbox2)
        return root
if __name__ == '__main__':
    LineExtendedApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Properties` for the parameters that you want to be able to change. Then use a `kv` rule to create bindings (so that changes to a `Property` are automatically shown in your display). Here is an example of how to do that:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, NumericProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class LineRectangle(Widget):
    line_color = ListProperty([])
    line_rect = ListProperty([])
    line_width = NumericProperty()
    label_text = StringProperty('')
    label_pos = ListProperty([])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.line_color = kwargs.pop('line_color', [1,1,1,1])
        self.line_rect = kwargs.pop('line_rect', [0,0,50,50])
        self.line_width = kwargs.pop('line_width', 1)
        self.label_text = kwargs.pop('label_text', 'text')
        self.label_pos = kwargs.pop('label_pos', [0,0])
        super(LineRectangle, self).__init__()

Builder.load_string('''
<LineRectangle>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: root.line_color
        Line:
            width: root.line_width
            rectangle: root.line_rect
    Label:
        text: root.label_text
        pos: root.label_pos
        size: 10, 10
''')


class LineExtendedApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = FloatLayout()
        image = Image(source='000001.jpg', allow_stretch=False, keep_ratio=True)
        root.add_widget(image)
        self.bbox1 = LineRectangle(line_wdth=2, line_rect=[100, 100, 100, 100], line_color=[1,0,0,1], label_text='bbox1', label_pos=[100, 100])
        bbox2 = LineRectangle(line_width=1, line_rect=[300, 300, 300, 300], line_color=[0,1,0,1], label_text='bbox2', label_pos=[300, 300])
        root.add_widget(self.bbox1)
        root.add_widget(bbox2)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.adjust, 2)  # just to demonstrate change parameter
        return root

    def adjust(self, dt):
        self.bbox1.line_width = 10


if __name__ == '__main__':
    LineExtendedApp().run()
```